# Send file like data with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to send data with ajax to c# method. I getting files from `input type=file`

```
var inp = document.getElementById('file');
var data = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
   var somefile  = inp.files.item(i);
   //for is for later not have function right now!
}

$.ajax({
   url: "Main/Upload",
   type: "GET",
   data: {"file":somefile},
});
```

I write c# method:

```
public void Upload(HttpPostedFileWrapper file)
{
   ModelState.Clear();
   if (file != null)
   {
     if (file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
       var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/tmp"), fileName);
       file.SaveAs(saveLocation);
     }
   }           
}
```

I am not sure that `HttpPostedFileWrapper` is right option but I try... It is problem to use [httpost] because otter issues.

Now ajax call not call Upload.

I get error `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object`.

I try to debug in somefile i get file size,name,type etc.

I need to get file from input without submit, i do that,and that part work, now i just need to `save file in save folder`, maybei can do only with jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your ajax code is wrong.

The above code can be rewritten as

```
var inp = document.getElementById('file');
var data = new FormData();
data.append("fileInfo", inp);

/*
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
   var somefile  = inp.files.item(i);
   //for is for later not have function right now!
}*/

$.ajax({
   url: "Main/Upload",
   type: "POST",
   data: data,
   success : function (data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
   },
   error : function () {
    console.log("ERROR");
   }
});
```